# Global.asax, definition of routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I have a question about global.asax that I don't really understand. My scenario is that I have this route defined :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Suspensions",
                "Suspension/{action}/{id}/{prev}",
                new { controller = "Suspension", action = "Index", id = "", prev = "" }
                );
```

The thing is that when I call it like:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditTemporal", new { id = item.TCtsRecID,
                                                  prev = previousPage})%>
```

I get the following route generated:

```
http://localhost:1537/Suspension/EditTemporal/3941?prev=1
```

What I really expected it to do would be `http://localhost:1537/Suspension/EditTemporal/3941/1`, because I'm using the split method to get the options passed and show or hide parts of the page depending on the last parameter.  Could you tell me what am I doing wrong for not getting it as I want it? I know there are some ways round this, but I would like this specific solution, as it is what I'm suppossed to do.

Thank you all!
VIctor

Comment: +1 - Well asked, code, result, expected result and brief description, I wish most questions were like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it could be possibly hitting the Default route. Have you checked that your Suspensions route is defined before (above) the default route?